# What is the proper url format to bring in the new (preview) Weather tile layer in Azure Maps?

Tags: azure-maps

Microsoft recently announced the preview of Azure Maps Weather Service (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/rain-or-shine-azure-maps-weather-services-will-bring-insights-to-your-enterprise/).

I'm trying to use the Weather Tile service but can't seem to find any documentation on how to access this.  For example, to use the basic Azure Maps layer you can use: [https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/tile/png?api-version=1.0&layer=basic&style=main&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}&subscription-key={key-goes-here}](https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/tile/png?api-version=1.0&layer=basic&style=main&zoom=%7Bz%7D&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&subscription-key=%7Bkey-goes-here%7D)

Is it possible to retrieve the weather layer in a similar way?  If so, what's the structure of the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following url:

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/tile
```

With the following [URI parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/render/getmaptile#uri-parameters):

```
?subscription-key={subscription-key}&api-version=2.0&tilesetId={layerName}&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}
```

---

> **Weather Tile API:** Fetches radar and infrared raster weather tiles
>   formatted to be integrated into the Azure Maps SDKs.

Use `tilesetId=microsoft.weather.radar.main` or `tilesetId=microsoft.weather.infrared.main` to fetch the desired weather tile.

---

Take a look at this sample [Show weather overlays on a map](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/REST%20Services/Show%20weather%20overlays%20on%20a%20map.html) by Ricky Brundritt.